# onPostExecute retrieves null from server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I trying read data from server by using AsyncTask, but when i give the parameter to onPostExecute, it retrieves me null.The MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

EditText name, password;
Button login;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            String outputasync = uiUpdate.getText().toString();
            String serverURL = "http://192.168.1.105/myapp/text.php";
            LongOperation longOperation = new LongOperation(MainActivity.this);
            longOperation.execute(serverURL);
            longOperation.onPostExecute(uiUpdate);
        }
    });



}
```

The AsyncTask:

```
public class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


private Context mcontext;
private String content;
private String error = null;
AlertDialog alertDialog;


public LongOperation(Context context){
    mcontext = context ;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        client.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));                                   
        content = bufferedReader.readLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        client.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }

    return null;
}

 protected void onPostExecute(TextView unused) {

    alertDialog.dismiss();

    if (error != null) {

        unused.setText("Output : " + error);

    } else {

        unused.setText("Output : "+ content);

    }

}


}
```

The connectivity to server is correct, the problem is display the message inside the server in the TextView.

### Upadte and solution

Like androholic said :

> You should not be calling onPostExecute manually from your code. Calling execute on the asynctask should suffice. onPostExecute will automatically be called when the asynctask finishes its work.

And change the onPostExecute parameter to String

And for retrieve a TextView with the message of the server, i did what Sharj said:

> 2) How to set your TextView that is in your Activity. The simplest way is to pass activity variable to LongOperation constructor and use that for accessing TextView in onPostExecute.

The AsyncTask:

```
public class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
TextView textviews;
private Context mcontext;
private String content;
private String error = null;
AlertDialog alertDialog;


public LongOperation(Context context, TextView textView){
    textviews = textView;
    mcontext = context ;


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        client.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        content = bufferedReader.readLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        client.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }

    return null;
}
    @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

    alertDialog.dismiss();

        if (error != null) {

        unused=("Output : " + error);
            textviews.setText(unused);

    } else {

        unused=("Output : "+ content);
            textviews.setText(unused);


    }

}
```

The MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

EditText name, password;
Button login;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            String outputasync = uiUpdate.getText().toString();
            String serverURL = "http://192.168.1.105/myapp/text.php";
            LongOperation longOperation = new   LongOperation(MainActivity.this, uiUpdate);
            longOperation.execute(serverURL, outputasync);

        }
 });



}
```

Note: doInBackground still working with "return = null" because im just using it for read the data inside the server, not for retrieve it anywhere.

Comment: Don't call onPostExecute yourself.  This is called on your behalf when the task finishes.

Comment: because you make doinbackgroudn return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the problem in your Activity:

```
 LongOperation longOperation = new LongOperation(MainActivity.this);
 longOperation.execute(serverURL);
 longOperation.onPostExecute(uiUpdate);
```

`longOperation.execute(serverURL);` is an asynchronous method. Which means your program will call `longOperation.onPostExecute(uiUpdate);` right after execute method without waiting for the results in `doInBackground`.

You can't do that and you shouldn't do that. `onPostExecute` is automatically called after `doInBackground` returns result (which you return `null` right now.)

LongOperation longOperation = new LongOperation(MainActivity.this);
longOperation.execute(serverURL);
longOperation.onPostExecute(uiUpdate);

Now the solution:

1) `doInBackground` return type should always be equal to `onPostExecute` parameter.

If you are return String then `onPostExecute`  will look like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
}
```

2) How to set your `TextView` that is in your `Activity`. The simplest way is to pass activity variable to `LongOperation` constructor and use that for accessing TextView in `onPostExecute`.

3) How to send data to `onPostExecute`? You have to return it in method:

```
@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         // do anything here.
         return "String"; //Since return type is String. You can change that you anything and make sure it matches `onPostExecute` parameter type.
}
```

Comment: @BerryBerry if it fixes your problem then you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be calling `onPostExecute` manually from your code. Calling `execute` on the asynctask should suffice. `onPostExecute` will automatically be called when the asynctask finishes its work.

Comment: Also, pass your uiUpdate textview in the asynctask constructor. That way you can update it in the onpostexecute method when the taks's job is done.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that im looking to retrieve a text for a TextView, so if im call only the execute, i will only be able to pass Strings, as i using String,Void,String. I tryed to convert the TextView in a String, but it happened the same problem that before, that im passing a String to the onPostExecute, so im not able to put the data inside the TextView and retrieve it to the MainActivity.

Comment: Your onPostExecute method should have a String argument and not a TextView argument in the first place. Secondly, once you get the string in the onPostExecute method, you can display that string using the textview passed in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `doInBackground()` method only returns null.  Ever.

Your `onPostExecute()` method isn't called because it isn't overriding `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` method, which would take a `String` argument

Comment: So how can i retrieve the TextView to the MainActivity, if im passing a String?